# How upload image in my root folder?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have successfully manage to upload my images to c:/images
 How can I upload the in my root folder?

```
String fileName = getFileName(filePart);
                          FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("C:/images" + fileName);
                          os.write(b);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ServletContext.getRealPath(relativePath)` to obtain the real path of file.

```
String relativePath="/images/" + fileName;
String realPath=getServletContext().getRealPath(relativePath);
FileOutputStream stream=new FileOutputStream(realPath);
```